# Fedora bootloader disappeared from BIOS

Tags: linux, fedora, windows, dual-boot

I have an Acer laptop with Windows 10 dual booted with Fedora. In the BIOS there were two options where I could set either "Windows Boot Manager" or "Fedora" to boot.

After servicing my laptop to get the internal fan replaced, I'm now unable to boot into Fedora. The option which was there in BIOS for Fedora has disappeared and only Windows remains.

The partitions for Fedora are all intact when checked in disk management.

Could anyone please help me restore Fedora in BIOS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check whether you're using legacy BIOS or UFI?

In UFI mode modern PCs have option to browse and select bootloader UFI file. If so please press `f2` just after power on and from bios screen browse `grubx64.efi` in `\boot` section of Fedora. Set this bootloader at higher priority than Windows. Your machine shall boot Fedora after a reboot.

If you're using legacy BIOS, boot up the system with live fedora cd.. `chroot` into the fedora `\` partition and reinstall grub. Google for the grub reinstallation procedure. This process shall work with UFI also.

Update grub menu entry correctly and you can `chainload` Windows also from `grub` bootloader

Comment: I'm using UEFI mode, but I don't have the option to browse and select the file. The problem is, where "Fedora" used to be there, it now shows "HDD: ". I set this as higher priority than windows bootloader but still went back to windows without going to grub2

Comment: It's looking like somehow the Fedora bootloader has been corrupted. Please boot using live cd, `chroot` into your fedora installation, and reinstall `grub`

Comment: Will try the above method and get back to you.